# What is the difference between UIView and UIViewController?

Tags: ios, class, uiview, uiviewcontroller, composition

I need a detailed explanation on the following:

What do we use a `UIViewController` for?
What is the use of it?

I have a class that looks like the following:

```
class one
{
    UINavigationController *nav = ...;

    two *secondObject = ...;

    // By use of it, I have push the new view class two//ok
}
class two
{
 ...
}
```

How can I use `secondObject` in the class `one`?

What is the class hierarchical start from the window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `UIViewController` is the controller part in the **`MVC`** design pattern.

**`Model`**`<------->`**`Controller`**`<------->`**`View`**

The controller's task is to handle navigation between different views, key presses, and screen touches etc.

Answer (score 8):

A view is merely an object, kind of like a piece of paper, that other objects are put onto.

A View Controller is an object that controls views, pushing and popping them forwards and backwards in a navigation stack.

"[View Controllers Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/)"