# view and viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am a new iphone app developer.I want to know what is the difference between view and viewcontroller.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669783/what-is-the-difference-between-view-and-viewcontroller-in-iphone                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3658727/difference-between-view-and-view-controller-technically

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669783/what-is-the-difference-between-view-and-viewcontroller-in-iphone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**[UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html)**

> The UIView class defines a rectangular
>   area on the screen and the interfaces
>   for managing the content in that area.
>   At runtime, a view object handles the
>   rendering of any content in its area
>   and also handles any interactions with
>   that content. The UIView class itself
>   provides basic behavior for filling
>   its rectangular area with a background
>   color. More sophisticated content can
>   be presented by subclassing UIView and
>   implementing the necessary drawing and
>   event-handling code yourself. The
>   UIKit framework also includes a set of
>   standard subclasses you can use, which
>   range from simple buttons to complex
>   tables. For example, a UILabel object
>   draws a text string and a UIImageView
>   object draws an image.
>
> Because your application interacts
>   with the user primarily through view
>   objects, those objects have a number
>   of responsibilities. Here are just a
>   few:
>
> Drawing and animation A view draws
>   content in its rectangular area using
>   technologies such as UIKit, Core
>   Graphics, and OpenGL ES. Some view
>   properties can be animated to new
>   values. Layout and subview management
>   A view may contain zero or more
>   subviews. Each view defines its own
>   default resizing behavior in relation
>   to its parent view. A view can
>   manually change the size and position
>   of its subviews as needed. Event
>   handling A view is a responder and can
>   handle touch events and other events
>   defined by the UIResponder class. A
>   view can use the addGestureRecognizer:
>   method to install gesture recognizers
>   to handle common gestures.

**[UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**

> The UIViewController class provides
>   the fundamental view-management model
>   for iPhone applications. The basic
>   view controller class supports the
>   presentation of an associated view,
>   support for managing modal views, and
>   support for rotating views in response
>   to device orientation changes.
>   Subclasses such as
>   UINavigationController and
>   UITabBarController provide additional
>   behavior for managing complex
>   hierarchies of view controllers and
>   views.
>
> You use each instance of
>   UIViewController to manage a view
>   hierarchy. A typical view hierarchy
>   consists of a root view—a reference to
>   which is available in the view
>   property of this class—and usually one
>   or more subviews presenting the actual
>   content. On iPhone and iPod touch, the
>   root view typically fills the entire
>   screen but on iPad this view may fill
>   only part of the screen. In both
>   cases, the view controller is
>   responsible for managing the entire
>   view hierarchy, including all
>   subviews.
>
> View controllers are tightly bound to
>   the views they manage and take part in
>   the responder chain used to handle
>   events. View controllers are
>   themselves descendants of the
>   UIResponder class and are inserted
>   into the responder chain between the
>   managed root view and its superview,
>   which typically belongs to a different
>   view controller. If the view
>   controller’s view does not handle an
>   event, the view controller itself has
>   the option of handling the event
>   before passing the event along to the
>   superview.
>
> The UIViewController class works with
>   the application’s window to handle
>   device orientation changes. If the
>   view controller supports the new
>   orientation (as determined by the
>   return value of its
>   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
>   method), it animates the transition
>   from the current orientation to the
>   new one. As part of this change, it
>   also applies any resizing rules in
>   effect for the views in its view
>   hierarchy. If you want to make changes
>   to your view hierarchy as part of the
>   orientation change, you can override
>   methods of UIViewController to
>   implement your changes. For
>   information on the methods you need to
>   override, see “Handling View
>   Rotations.”
>
> View controllers are fundamental to
>   the design of most iPhone
>   applications. The sections that follow
>   provide basic information about using
>   the methods and properties of the
>   UIViewController class. For additional
>   information about using view
>   controllers to build and manage your
>   application’s user interface, see View
>   Controller Programming Guide for iOS.

Comment: Ah! Looked like a plain header :-)

Comment: ;) Yeaaaah may be! But its not ;)

Answer (score 7):

[A `UIViewController` instance manages a hierarchy of `UIView` instances.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Read up on the [Model-View-Controller pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32) that embodies the design of most iOS apps.

Comment: @Siju: If this answers your question your should accept the answer.

Answer (score 5):

ViewController - Main Screen

View - component that can be added to ViewController

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the Model-View-Controller pattern? Before even starting iPhone development, you should be familiar with it. I recommend the book [Cocoa Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321535022). Trust me, it will help **a lot** in the long term.