# Loading new view shows blank screen in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Please note that I am trying to learn iphone and for this problem, i can't figure out any solution.

I have created an empty view with the name of Loading. I have filled its Loading.xib with some images. Now this is the code I am using

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    Loading *firstView = [[Loading alloc]init];


    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init]; 
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstView animated:YES];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The problem is , when ever i run the code, it just shows the blank screen.

How can i load the loading screen. Any recommended tutorial links are welcomed

```
@implementation Loading

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Loading is a view not view controller. You shouldn't push it with navigation controller.

Secondly, it is not a good idea to add the navigation controller's view to the window.

Please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5789009/609086) for more detail about `UIView` and `UIViewController`

Instead, you may want to create a LoadingViewController, and change its view(XIB file) as what you want, then use code like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
LoadingViewController *lvc= [[LoadingViewController alloc]init];

self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:lvc]; 
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: it is a viewcontroller. I have made it a view controller. secondly , i cant make a loading screen root right?

Comment: You can. Just use self.window.rootViewController = loading. But did you create the XIB file manually or with the class? If the former case, you may need to use initWithNibName.

Comment: i didn't create manually, it came with the class . Please check my edited code for loading.m

Comment: solved with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati

Answer (score 1):

--> "Loading.xib" <--

You're never loading this, so unless the instance of "Loading"'s init: selector does some fancy stuff, this view is empty.

EDIT FOR: "can you explain a bit how can i call this? "

override init... *

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"SomeNib" bundle:nil])) {
        // ...
    }

    return self;
}
```

*
if the owner and nib don't match in IB, you either A) create the rationship properly in IB or B) do it manually in code:

update init:

```
[super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]
```

override:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SomeNib" bundle:nil];
    [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
}
```

Comment: can you explain a bit how can i call this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the view from its nib file. Here is an example:

```
Loading *firstView = [[Loading alloc] initWithNibName:@"Loading" bundle:nil];
```

Also, when you alloc your UINavigationController, you can set its root view controller property as well, rather than having to push the view like this:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: firstView];
```

Comment: explain a bit further please. I didn't quite understand. where should i put this code.

Comment: His answer is pretty complete; the Apple documentation is also very complete about loading your views from nib..

Comment: I Dont want it to be root, but i tried your code. its the blank page as usual. My view is UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the code like,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    Loading *firstView = [[Loading alloc] initWithNibName:@"Loading" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init]; 
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstView animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: NOT WOrking, anymore tips? :S

Comment: open your MainWindow.xib. Select the `NavigationController`. Go to Inspector. Set NIB name as your `Loading` viewController. Save and run. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

If someone found this thread, but still not able to figure it out. Try this. I forgot to add target membership for that view controller.

[image]